# C++ - Else Returning Elseif

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to learn C++. When I try to do `else`, it isn't working how I think it should.

I have tried everything I can think of.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[50];
    int text;
    int text2;

    cout << "Enter 1-2: ";
    cin >> name;
    string s = name;

    text = atoi(s.c_str());
    if (text == 1) {
        cout << "You selected 1";
    }
    else if (text == 0) {
        cout << "You selected 0";
    }
    else if (text == 3) {
        cout << "You selected 3";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid number";
    }
}
```

If I enter numbers, it works correctly. However, if I enter something that isn't a number, e.g. `abcd`, it prints `You selected 0`, but I want it to print `Invalid number`.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to tell us the input you give the program, and the expected as well as actual output.

Comment: Can you show some example input and output, with what you expected the output to be? I just tried to run this, and it does what seems to be intended.

Comment: @BoBTFish its supposed to output "Invalid number" when you enter anything but 1, 0, or 3. but it outputs 0.. it only outputs 0 if you enter text instead of numbers

Comment: A few other (unrelated) points: What use is the `text2` variable? Why did you name an integer variable used as a choice `text`, that's pretty misleading? What use is the array or the temporary variable `s`? Why not use `string name;` directly? And if you use `std::string` you really should include `<string>`. Lastly, if you want to get an integer choice, why not input directly to such a variable? As in `int choice; cin >> choice;`.

Comment: @DeaganMuir I hope you don't mind, I have edited your question to more clearly describe the problem. Stephan Lechner's answer explains why this occurs.

Answer (score 5):

If you pass a value to `atoi` that cannot be converted, e.g. when you pass "text", then the return value of `atoi` is `0`. Confer, for example, [atoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) description on cppreference.com:

> **Return value** Integer value corresponding to the contents of str on success. If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding
>   return type, the return value is undefined. **If no conversion can be
>   performed, ​0​ is returned.**

To check conversion errors, you could use `stol`, which throws an exception on conversion errors:

```
string invalid_num = "text, i.e. invalid number"; 
int num=0;
try{ 
    num = (int)stol(invalid_num); 
} 
catch(const std::invalid_argument){ 
    cerr << "Invalid argument" << "\n"; 
    num = -1;
}
```

Output:

```
Invalid argument
```

Comment: Note, exceptions should be caught by reference, not by value : `catch (const std::invalid_argument &)`